# Using Konva with next js

Tags: next.js, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

i founded that most of konva documentation is on native javascript dom and im used to work on next js with complex tasks using konva... how to deal with native js in next ? Thanks

There was some limited konva tools but still more complex to deal with dom

Comment: Join the Konva discord channel and ask there. This type of 'how to' question is not well suited to SO.